# How to add ghost text or place holder text for textFields in Adobe Acrobat using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, adobe, textfield

I am looking to add "ghost text" or placeholder text that is grey when it is the default value and black when the user has entered in information in Adobe Acrobat that still works when the PDF is downloaded from being sent in an e-mail.
I have code that works in Adobe Acrobat but not when the PDF is downloaded. The text remains grey even when the user types something in.

```
// On Focus script:
if (event.target.value==event.target.defaultValue) {   event.target.value = "";   event.target.textColor = color.black;}
// On Blur script:
if (event.target.value=="") {   event.target.value = event.target.defaultValue;   event.target.textColor = color.ltGray;}
```

I have tried using the custom format block and using code in there to try to get it to work. I've contacted Adobe but I can't seem to find a solution to my problem.

Comment: Okay, interesting. Even for an editable pdf using textFields instead of static text?

Comment: So I should be able to change the text color?